# Any way to get a callback when a conference participant has been on hold for a certain amount of time?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I have a need to put someone in the system I'm building on hold in a conference while they are either transferred to someone / department or otherwise waiting for someone to "pick up their call" (enter the conference and remove them from hold).

What I would like is a way to play a message to the caller that says something to the effect of, press 1 to remain on hold, press 2 to leave a voice mail.

I understand functionally how to get this input with redirects and gather verbs, but is there a way to get some sort of callback or notification that the participant has been on hold for say 2 minutes and handle redirecting them to an endpoint that collects their input?

Off the top of my head I might consider a cron of some kind but would love to avoid that if possible

Comment: I've wondered this also. Not that it's of much help (but perhaps it may) this was my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74693186/what-is-the-best-way-to-achieve-a-constant-callback-every-x-seconds-to-a-script